# ScrollViewer in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, scrollview

In my app, I have wrapped a scrollviewer around a grid.

```
    ScrollViewer Height="420" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Foreground="#FF0000DE" Background="#003B27FF" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource LeftScrollViewer}"><!--{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}-->
            <Grid>
<!--some controls-->
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The problem is that to enable scrolling i should have a height attribute with the scrollviewer (it can't be auto as then it will automatically regulate, and not scroll).
But then this height will be different for different phones, so how can i adapt?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your ScrollViewer in Grid which has few Rows defined by star notation.

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"></ScrollViewer>
 </Grid>
```

In this situation your scrollviewer will always have size of half window.